# android building with device sources

Tags: android

I deleted my local device sources. Now I am getting this error, if I am trying to sync the source:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/tools/roomservice.py", line 61, in <module>
    result = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen("https://api.github.com/users/AICP/repos?page=%d" % page).read())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
build/core/product_config.mk:239: *** _nic.PRODUCTS.[[vendor/aicp/products/i9300.mk]]: "vendor/samsung/smdk4412-common/common-vendor.mk" does not exist.  Stop.
```